# Stripe Recurring Payments but every 3 or 6 months

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-cashier

I'm new to Stripe PHP Laravel. Are recurring payments in Laravel Stripe possible for billing cycles that are not 1 month but 3 months or 6 months? Can anyone send me to the right documentation because I'm not familiar with the term? I have checked cycles in Stripe but I don't think that's what I need.

Comment: Not sure why all the downvotes for a very valid question. I found it very hard to find information about changing the intervals for Cashier/Stripe - thanks for asking, and glad there's an answer here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On stripe dashboard under belling-> products create new product for example prod-1 , add pricing plan for example plan-1(stripe will generate ID for this plan) to that product(prod-1), while adding pricing plan under billing interval select or customize the interval that you want.

Now let work on laravel app side. I will recommend to use Laravel Cashier.

Run Composer `composer require laravel/cashier`

Update your USER Migration Table:

```
 Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->string('stripe_id')->nullable()->collation('utf8mb4_bin');
    $table->string('card_brand')->nullable();
    $table->string('card_last_four', 4)->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();
});

Schema::create('subscriptions', function ($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('stripe_id')->collation('utf8mb4_bin');
    $table->string('stripe_plan');
    $table->integer('quantity');
    $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('ends_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Update Your User Model:

```
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Billable;
}
```

In your Controller ex. MyController.php:

```
use Cartalyst\Stripe\Laravel\Facades\Stripe;
use Cartalyst\Stripe\Exception\CardErrorException;
use Session;
use Auth;

public function store(Request $request)
{

    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $user = Auth::user();

    try {

        $user->newSubscription('prod-1', 'ID of plan-1')->create($token);

        Session::flash('success', 'You are now a premium member');
        return redirect()->back();

    } catch (CardErrorException $e) {
        return back()->withErrors('Error!'.  $e->getMessage());
    }


}
```

In your view:

```
<form action="{{ route('subscribe')}}" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_0000000000000000000" // Your api key
    data-image="/images/marketplace.png" // You can change this image to your image
    data-name="My App Name"
    data-description="Subscription for 1 weekly box"
    data-amount="2000" //the price is in cents 2000 = 20.00
    data-label="Sign Me Up!">
  </script>
</form>
```

Create Route:

```
Route::POST('subscription', 'MyController@store')->name('susbcribe');
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: thanks. I really wondered why this question got downvoted. turns out, this setting is available in Stripe. thank you very much!

Comment: @James Arnold, it's because you didn't post any code with your question. The rule here is that you have to share codes where you got stuck so people can take a look and help you out instead of starting from scratch.